# mode for impute missing value in Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, weka, missing-data

I want to fill missing values pandas.dataframe.mode. I got  `df.fillna(df.mode().iloc[0])` from [this link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mode.html) but I can not understand the working principal of mode.

My dataset is a categorical dataset.

I would also like to know is there any method in Weka to fill the missing values using `mode`?

Comment: You can check out this option as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74295669/16733101

Answer (score 1):

The [ReplaceMissingValues](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/ReplaceMissingValues.html) filter inserts means (numeric attributes) and modes (nominal attributes).

If you want more options for injecting missing values or replacing them, check out the following (unofficial) Weka package:

https://github.com/fracpete/missing-values-imputation-weka-package